# \hrulefill for digital signs

Tags: graphics

I'm trying to add a place for digital signs like this

```
\vspace*{0.65cm}
\hspace*{3.5in}\hrulefill \includegraphics[width=0.2\textheight]{sign} \\
\hspace*{0cm} \hfill {Test}\\
\hspace*{0cm} \hfill Test
```

but this is the result
[image]

The image (pdf with transparent background) doesn't go above the horizontal line with `\hrulefill`. How can I get an horizontal line with the image on it? I would like that the line doesn't go exactly under the image, but I want that the image overlaps the line. Possibly without using tables...

Comment: What do you want exactly? That whatever in that image go above the line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it something like this you want?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx, mwe} 
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\vspace*{0.65cm}
\raggedleft\includegraphics[width=0.2\textheight]{example-image-a} \\[-7.8ex]
\hspace*{2.5in}{\color{red}\hrulefill} \\[7.8ex]
\hspace*{0cm} \hfill {Test}\\
\hspace*{0cm} \hfill Test

\end{document}
```

[image]